# Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: (0, _context2.t0) is not a function. (In '(0, _context2.t0 )(_context2.t1)', '(0, _context2.t0)' is undefined)

Tags: javascript, react-native, typeerror, fetch-api, unhandled-promise-rejection

I am using expo go and react native to create an app to handle storage for products. I am trying to set a products stock in an API by name, id and stock by the method PUT. I can set the order but whatever I am stuck at the product update.

I get this error message in the terminal and a console.log() of the data for the API body where I want to change the data:

```
Object {
  "api_key": "65054948e5528b34cfc9ec09db084840",
  "id": 27441,
  "name": "Mutter M10",
  "stock": 6,
}

[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: (0, _context2.t0) is not a function. (In '(0, _context2.t0
)(_context2.t1)', '(0, _context2.t0)' is undefined)]
at components\PickList.tsx:26:4 in pick
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:294:29 in invoke
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:36 in tryCatch
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:155:27 in invoke
at node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:165:18 in PromiseImpl.resolve.then$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:13 in tryCallOne
at node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:24 in setImmediate$argum
ent_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:123:14 in _callTimer
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:177:14 in _callImmediatesPass
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:437:30 in callImmediates
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:388:6 in __callImmediates
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:132:6 in __guard$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:365:10 in __guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:131:4 in flushedQueue
```

the model file product.ts looks like this:

```
import config from "../config/config.json";


const orders = {
    getProducts: async function getProducts() {
        const response = await fetch(`${config.base_url}/products?api_key=${config.api_key}`);
        const result = await response.json();

    return result.data;
},
updateProduct: async function updateProduct(products) {
    console.log(products);
    try {
        products.api_key = config.api_key;

        await fetch(`${config.base_url}/products?api_key=${config.api_key}`, {
            body: JSON.stringify(products),
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json'
            },
            method: 'PUT'
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Could not update product!")
    }
    }
};

export default orders;
```

The file orders.ts in the same map as products.ts:

```
    import config from "../config/config.json";

import product from "./products";
import Order from "../interfaces/order";
import OrderItem from "../interfaces/order_item";

const orders = {
    getOrders: async function getOrders(): Promise<Order[]> {
        const response = await fetch(`${config.base_url}/orders?api_key=${config.api_key}`);
        const result = await response.json();

        return result.data;
    },
    pickOrder: async function pickOrder(order: Partial<Order>) {
        await Promise.all(order.order_items.map(async(order_item:
            Partial<OrderItem>) => {
                let changeProduct = {
                    id: order_item.product_id, 
                    name: order_item.name,
                    stock: order_item.stock - order_item.amount,
                    

api_key: config.api_key,
                };
                await product.updateProduct(changeProduct);
            }));

        let changedOrder = {
            id: order.id,
            name: order.name,
            status_id: 200,
            api_key: config.api_key,
        };

        await orders.updateOrder(changedOrder);
    },

    updateOrder: async function updateOrder(order: Partial<Order>) {
        try {
            await fetch(`${config.base_url}/orders?api_key=${config.api_key}`, {
                body: JSON.stringify(order),
                headers: {
                    'content-type': 'application/json'
                },
                method: 'PUT'
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Could not update order!")
        }
    }
};

export default orders;
```

And the file PickList that the pickOrder function is called from:

```
    import { View, Text, Button } from "react-native";
import { Base, Typography } from "../styles";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {useRoute} from '@react-navigation/native';

import orderModel from "../models/orders";
import productModel from "../models/products";

export default function PickList({ route, navigation, setProducts }) {
    const { reload } = route.params || false;
    const { order } = route.params;
    const [productsList, setProductsLists] = useState([]);

    if (reload) {
        reloadProducts();
    }

    async function reloadProducts() {
        setProductsLists(await productModel.getProducts());
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        reloadProducts();
    }, []);

    async function pick() {
        await orderModel.pickOrder(order);
        setProducts(await  productModel.getProducts());
        navigation.navigate("List", {reload: true});
    }

    const productsHash = productsList.reduce((hash, current) => ({...hash, [current.id]: current.stock}), {});

    let allInStock = true;

    const orderItemsList = order.order_items.map((item, index) => {
        if (productsHash[item.product_id] < item.account) {
            allInStock = false;
        }
        
        return <Text
                key={index}
                >
                    {item.name} - antal: {item.amount} st - lagerplats: {item.location}
            </Text>;
    });

    return (
        <View>
            <Text>{order.name}</Text>
            <Text>{order.address}</Text>
            <Text>{order.zip} {order.city}</Text>

            <Text>Produkter:</Text>

            {orderItemsList}

            {allInStock
                ?<Button color="#f85d16" title="Plocka order" onPress={pick} />
                :<Text>Ordern går inte att packa, då varor saknas</Text>
            }
        </View>
    )
};
```

Where is the error that I can't find?